# Find the intersection points

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I try to find the intersection points of the following pair of projective curve:
$$P(x,y,z)=x(y^2-xz)^2-y^5$$
and
$$Q(x,y,z)=y^4+y^3z-x^2z^2$$

I tried to calculate $P=Q$ and to expand both sides but I oversee how I should now proceed:
$$xy^4-2x^2y^2z+x^3z^2-y^5=y^4+y^3z-x^2z^2$$

How can I now continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the affine chart $y = 1$, setting $u = xz$, the equations simplify to $u(1-u)^2 = z$ and $u^2 = z + 1$. Eliminating $z$ we get $u^3 - 3u^2 + u + 1 = 0$, so $u = 1$ (extraneous), or $u = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}$ which produces the points $[1 : 2 : 4(1 \pm \sqrt{2})]$.

On $y = 0$ the equations reduce to $x^3 z^2 = 0$ and $x^2 z^2 = 0$, so you get the two points $[0:0:1]$ and $[1:0:0]$.

I will omit the computation of the multiplicities of intersection (which should add up to $5 \times 4 = 20$) since the question did not ask for them.

Answer (score 2):

In M2

```
R=QQ[x,y,z];I=ideal(x*(y^2-x*z)^2-y^5,y^4+y^3*z-x^2*z^2)
primaryDecomposition I -- {ideal(y^2*z-x*z^2+y*z^2-z^3,z^4,y*z^3,y^4-x^2*z^2+x*y*z^2-x*z^3), ideal(x^3-3*x^2*y-3*y^3+3*x^2*z,y^4+y^3*z-x^2*z^2,x*y^3-3*x^2*y*z-3*y^3*z+3*x^2*z^2,x^2*y^2-x^2*y*z-y^3*z+x^2*z^2), ideal(2*x-y,4*y^2+4*y*z-z^2)}
```

In maxima CAS

```
solve([2*x-y,4*y^2+4*y*z-z^2],[x,y,z]); # [[x = %r1,y = 2*%r1,z = (2^(5/2)+4)*%r1], [x = %r2,y = 2*%r2,z = (4-2^(5/2))*%r2]]
solve([y^2*z-x*z^2+y*z^2-z^3,z^4,y*z^3,y^4-x^2*z^2+x*y*z^2-x*z^3],[x,y,z]); -- [[x = %r3,y = 0,z = 0]]
solve([x^3-3*x^2*y-3*y^3+3*x^2*z,y^4+y^3*z-x^2*z^2,x*y^3-3*x^2*y*z-3*y^3*z+3*x^2*z^2,x^2*y^2-x^2*y*z-y^3*z+x^2*z^2],[x,y,z]); # [[x = 0,y = 0,z = %r4]]
```

So the solutions seem to be $(1:2:4+4\sqrt2),(1 : 2 : (4-4\sqrt2)),(1:0:0), (0:0:1).$